# ¿Por que esta mal este Trigger de MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Me da error de Sintaxis ¿Por que?

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER busqueda 
AFTER INSERT 
ON activas_ips 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT IP FROM datos_Mall WHERE IP = New.IP)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO datos_Mall 
(Email) VALUES (New.Email);
END; //
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

el error que obtengo es:

**[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
INSERT INTO datos_Mall 
(Email) VALUES (New.Email);
END; //
END; //
D' at line 7**

el problema a mi duda es que creo:

```
SELECT IF 
(
condicion,
verdadera,
falsa
);
```

y esto no aplica solo en MSSQL? o si aplica en mysql? por que ahora no se como usar esta sentencia.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT IP FROM datos_Mall WHERE IP = New.IP)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO datos_Mall 
(Email) VALUES (New.Email);
END; //
```

INTENTANDO con esta otra y tampoco:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER busqueda 
AFTER INSERT 
ON activas_ips 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SELECT IF 
(
NULL<>SELECT IP FROM datos_Mall WHERE IP = New.IP,
INSERT INTO datos_Mall (Email) VALUES (New.Email);,
'NO ENTRO'
)
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Creo el error se consigue en la siguiente Sintaxis pero no se como diseñarla:

```
SELECT IF (NULL<>(SELECT IP FROM datos_Mall WHERE IP = NULL),
(INSERT INTO datos_Mall (Email) VALUES (1)),
'NO ENTRO')
```

Comment: Aunque yo **no** te voté negativo, considero oportuno nos compartas el error que obtienes para que de ese modo la comunidad te pudiera auxiliar de forma mas acotada

Comment: Listo amigo no entiendo por que votan negativo seguramente quien voto negativo debio nacer sabiendo caminar y de todo. gracias por responder amigo.

Comment: si puedes pasa la db o una parte mas completa del código para ver si el trigger está siendo obstruido, tambien revisa la linea con los values para el insert ya que veo que en el final termina con un " New.DiscordNew. " solo eso bro y suerte.

Comment: El primer bloque de código tiene dos `BEGIN`

Comment: si y tambien tiene 2 END eso no es error de sintaxis

Comment: Recuerde que existe el [IF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) y el [IF statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) (disculpe pero los enlaces redirigen a la documentación en Inglés). Entiendo que usted debería usar `IF statement`, con la sintaxis: `IF ... THEN ... END IF;`. Vea [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eff6983427d752f64ae3435fa8a47fda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error esta en esta linea:

```
                                  |           | 
                                  V           V                                        
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT IP FROM datos_Mall activas_ips WHERE IP = New.IP)
```

como veras, dentro de tu **FROM** haces mención de **datos_Mall** y **activas_ips** lo cual ocasiona un error de sintaxis ya que no están separadas por una coma (**,**)  y aunque lo hagas también tendrías un error ya que si usas dos tablas deberías relacionarlas por su clave primaria y foránea.

Aun así y sin saber tu lógica supongo solo quieres comprobar si existe en una sola tabla... si es así elimina la que esta demás.

---

**EDITADO**:

Tu error sigue siendo de sintaxis,... 
Te agrego estas modificaciones según la edición que hiciste a tu pregunta cambiando el delimitador y corrijiendo su uso en tu código:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER busqueda 
AFTER INSERT 
ON activas_ips 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT IP FROM datos_Mall WHERE IP = New.IP)
    INSERT INTO datos_Mall(Email) VALUES (New.Email);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

*Como sugerencia, si solo haces una sola instrucción dentro del* IF, *no uses begin-end, solo te complicas en su lectura. Usalo cuando realices más de una instrucción*

Comment: Eso lo sabia Ojala ese ubiera sido el error por apurado lo repeti disculpe pero el error sigue apareciendo y no es la doble eso es demasiado facil pero no se que detalle se me escapa

Comment: Vi tu edición y tus correcciones, pero no se entiende por qué pones las barras horizontales en 2 *END*... Tu delimitador no es ese, y si lo fuera solo debería ser usado al final del trigger... Voy a editar mi respuesta modificando tu propio código, por si las dudas

Comment: jajajaj ni yo se eso pense que era obligatorio

Comment: Hagalo a ver si me arranca por que me urges